# What mode do people use when using Emacs to edit web pages that contain CSS, javascript, and HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, emacs

typically the code is something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
       body { font-size:12pt; font-family: Arial;}
        ....
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.1.3.2js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        $(document).ready(function(){
          ...
        });
        ...
    -->
    </script>
    <meta ... />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <p>
       ....
      </p>
      ...
    </div>
    ....
  </body>
</html>
```

I like javascript-mode for the syntaxt highlighting and indenting.  Likewise for sgml-mode for the HTML.  Also I get auto-complete on the open tags.  Css-mode is not so important so it's not so much a priority.

That's 3 disparate languages and 3 modes.  Right now I've been swapping modes manually as I edit different sections.  This works, sort of.

Anyone got a better approach?

Comment: I see that on emacs questions often. Let me ask you: if I had asked how to set the code font in a Visual Studio window, or how to reconfigure an Eclipse perspective, would it belong on superuser?

Comment: No, because those are tools for programmers. :P

Comment: I'd like to see the rules amended that in order to get an Emacs question bumped to superuser.com, one of the voters must be Trey Jackson.  There is entirely too much knee-jerk reaction to Emacs questions belonging elsewhere, IMHO.

Comment: @Frank, you are spoiling for a fight. . . !

Comment: @pajato0 ha! ____ Though I do agree with the general feeling that it is a bad thing that Emacs questions get split between two communities (SO and SU).  e.g. on SU, there are roughly same number of visual studio (80) questions as emacs (70), but on SO, there are an order of magnitude more visual studio (10k) as emacs (1k).  Of course this comment belongs on meta...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think mumamo is generally used for this. http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MuMaMo

Comment: Yes, perfect. Clicking on the link I learned that the best way to get Mumamo is to download and install nXhtml mode. It's working perfectly.

Comment: Is nXhtml (MuMaMo) available for non-Win23 platforms? I'm running Debian Squeeze.

Comment: Apparently mumamo hasn't been updated for 4 years, whereas the newer web-mode is active. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21222987/48082)

Comment: As Cheeso said, as of 2015, Mumamo is old. As a professional web developer, web-mode is the answer, as mentioned below.

Answer (score 25):

Ever since [web-mode](http://web-mode.org/) came to existence, I have gotten rid of mumamo and nxhtml. web-mode is easier to use and install. For a start, it uses different syntax highlighting and indentation of a mixed js/html/css file. But for me the really handy thing about it is that it works in other templating languages. Here's an example configuration from their website:

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.phtml\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.tpl\\.php\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.jsp\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.as[cp]x\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.erb\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mustache\\'" . web-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.djhtml\\'" . web-mode))
```

Comment: How does one carry out tag insertion like C-c C-t in the default html mode in emacs in web-mode?

Comment: This must be marked as the right answer. web-mode just works, and  MuMaMo never worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

I use [nXhtml](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html) for emacs.  Quoting from the page

> One of the main parts of nXhtml is nxhtml-mode, a GNU Emacs major mode that builds on nxml-mode. It knows about XHTML syntax and can check this as you type. It can also tell you what tags and attributes you can use at a certain point and help you insert them.
>
> That feature, which we call completion, is one of the main features of this mode. Another important feature is the ability to mix several languages in one buffer and get the correct syntax highlighting and indentation for each of them.

Comment: nXhtml works great, but I am often happy with just sgml-mode.  The real tricky question is not "what mode to use for (X)HTML?", but "what mode to use for a file with mixed content?"

Comment: I take back every doubt I had about nXhtml mode.  The cool part about nXhtml is Mumamo mode, which does exactly what I described - it supports multiple modes in a single buffer.  I can edit and indent Javascript, CSS, and (X)HTML all in the same file. 
Nice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I'd be loathe to call my approach better, but fwiw, I avoid this situation like the plague by putting CSS into .css files and javascript into .js files and then put "include" tags in the html file.  Then Emacs handles each nicely.  Admittedly, having three, large monitors with full screen Emacs on each makes side by side buffers containing the files I need hardly painful at all. -:)  And it doesn't work real well in an enterprise environment where I don't have control over what other engineers choose to do.

Comment: Patient:  "It hurts when I do this, Doc."   Doctor:  "Don't do that."

Comment: I do this to, and when I can't (PHP and JSP code) I rely on nXhtml.

Answer (score 4):

By way of comparison, here are some of the available modes, as of 2014-07-04:

```
| library        | files | size    | last update | url                                                 |
|----------------+-------+---------+-------------+-----------------------------------------------------|
| web-mode       |     1 |  279 kb |  2014-07-03 | https://github.com/fxbois/web-mode                  |
| polymode       |     7 |  120 kb |  2014-06-14 | https://github.com/vitoshka/polymode                |
| mmm-mode       |    17 |  185 kb |  2014-02-12 | https://github.com/purcell/mmm-mode                 |
| multi-web-mode |     1 |   16 kb |  2013-08-23 | https://github.com/fgallina/multi-web-mode          |
| mumamo         |   115 | 3090 kb |  2010-04-25 | http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/nXhtml/doc/nxhtml.html |
| multi-mode     |     1 |   23 kb |        2009 | http://www.loveshack.ukfsn.org/emacs/multi-mode.el  |
```

Also added to the Emacs Wiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes

Answer (score 1):

Multi-web-mode is relatively new and is being actively updated, grab it from elpa (package.el)

You can see the source and docs here https://github.com/fgallina/multi-web-mode