# How do I configure emacs for editing HTML files that contain Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, emacs, lisp

I have started the painful first steps of using emacs to edit an HTML file with both HTML tags and javascript content.   I have installed nxhtml and tried using it - i.e set up to use nxhtml-mumamo-mode for .html files.  But I am not loving it.   When I am editing the Javascript portion of the code the tab indents do not behave as they do when editing C/C++ code.  It starts putting tabs within the line and if you try and hit tab in the white space preceding a line it inserts the tab rather than re-tabifying the line.

Another aspect that I don't like is that it doesn't do syntax colouring like the usual C/C++ modes do.  I much prefer the behaviour of the default java-mode when editing HTML files but that doesn't play nicely with the HTML code. :-(

1) Is there a better mode for editing HTML files with Javascript portions?

2) Is there a way to get nxhtml to use the default java-mode for the javascript portions?

Regards,

M

Comment: I use MMM-mode, which in theory does this but it's kind of sucky, I'm not really that happy with it.  I have pasted lots of lisp into my config from emacswiki but didn't really spend weeks on it.  I wish it were simpler for those of us more interested in using emacs than configuring it.

Comment: I guess a workaround is creating two files and referencing the javascript file with a `<script src>`. You can watch them both with a bit of `C-x 2` or `C-x 3` and have a mode for each. :-/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What mode do people use when using Emacs to edit web pages that contain CSS, javascript, and HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1909453/what-mode-do-people-use-when-using-emacs-to-edit-web-pages-that-contain-css-jav)

Answer (score 42):

Another solution is `multi-web-mode`:

https://github.com/fgallina/multi-web-mode

which may be more easily configurable than the already mentioned `multi-mode`.

You just configure your preferred modes in your `.emacs` file like this:

```
(require 'multi-web-mode)
(setq mweb-default-major-mode 'html-mode)
(setq mweb-tags 
  '((php-mode "<\\?php\\|<\\? \\|<\\?=" "\\?>")
    (js-mode  "<script[^>]*>" "</script>")
    (css-mode "<style[^>]*>" "</style>")))
(setq mweb-filename-extensions '("php" "htm" "html" "ctp" "phtml" "php4" "php5"))
(multi-web-global-mode 1)
```

More on Emacs's multiple multiple modes (sigh) here:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/MultipleModes

UPDATE: simplified the regexps to detect JavaScript or CSS areas to make them work with HTML5 -- no need for super-precise and fragile regular expressions.

Comment: I had troubles combining it with flymake

Comment: to handle more cases, like html5, I now use simpler and more forgiving tag descriptions for JavaScript and CSS: `(js-mode  "<script[^>]*>" "</script>") (css-mode "<style[^>]*>" "</style>")`

Answer (score 33):

I have written the major mode web-mode.el for this kind of usage : editing HTML templates that embed JS, CSS, Java (JSP), PHP. You can download it on http://web-mode.org
Web-mode.el does syntax highlighting and indentation according to the type of the block.
Installation is simple :

```
(require 'web-mode)
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.html$" . web-mode))
```

Comment: web-mode is also available as a package. At least from MELPA.

Comment: Has play/razor engine support!

Comment: Hi fxbois, why does not this work for me? I copied web-mode.el into /use/local/share/emacs/site-lisp/ (and removed all other .el files), and followed the "Install" section at web-mode.org (and .emacs file only has those few lines). Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: Could you load-file the we-mode.el file inside emacs and after M-x web-mode

Answer (score 14):

Great question. Look how many upvotes you got on your first one!

Everyone has the same experience as you.  Me too.

Rather than rely on nhtml-mode which exhibited the same sort of strangeness for me as you described, I looked for another option and found [multi-mode.el](http://www.loveshack.ukfsn.org/emacs/#multi-mode.el) .  It's a sort of general-purpose multi-mode skeleton.  To use it, you need to specify regular expressions to describe where one mode starts and another one ends.  So, you look for `<script...>` to start a javascript block, and `<style...>` to start a css block.  Then you plug in your own modes for each block - if you like espresso for javascript, use it.  And so on for the other regexes that identify other blocks.

In practice, as you navigate through the document, a different mode is enabled for each block.

I used multi-mode to produce an ASP.NET, that allows me to edit C#, HTML, CSS, and Javascript in a single file, with the proper highlighting and fontification depending on where the cursor is in the buffer.  It isn't perfect but I found it to be a marked improvement on the existing possibilities. In fact this may be what you want. Try it out.

https://code.google.com/p/csharpmode/source/browse/trunk/aspx-mode.el?r=14

Comment: I just got around to trying out the aspx-mode.  It worked great.  The only thing I did was change the javascript support from expresso-mode to javascript-mode.

Answer (score 8):

Not really a good solution but a quick fix if you really need to have javascript in your html is to select the region containing javascript and use the command `narrow-to-region`(`C-x n n`) and then switch to your preferred javascript mode. The command `widen` brings you back, (`C-x n w`).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've setup your nxhtml incorrectly. The only setup necessary should be loading the `autostart.el` file, and then everything should work to some level. nxhtml isn't perfect in any way, but my experiences from using it for html/css/javascript/mako is pretty good, at least for everything but mako. But I'm pretty sure I've screwed up with the mako-part.

This is how I initialize my nxhtml:

```
(when (load "autostart.el" t)
  (setq nxhtml-skip-welcome t
        mumamo-chunk-coloring 'submode-colored
        indent-region-mode t
        rng-nxml-auto-validate-flag nil))
```